# How can I catch a button clicked on mobile device with Flutter

Tags: flutter, zebra-printers

I am new to Flutter. I've been trying to develop an android application for a handheld terminal which model is ZEBRA.

I need to catch when a user clicks the barcode scanner button on the handled terminal.
If the User focuses on TextField, the Barcode value appears in the text field. But If it's not focused I need to catch what the barcode scanner read and get the value.

I found a package in Flutter --> hardware_buttons: ^1.0.0

But It gives only those 3 buttons

- VolumeButton
- HomeButton
- LockButton

How can I do that? or Is there any workaround method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

RawKeyboardListener can listen to the clicking buttons.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: buttonFocusNode,
        onKey: (event) {
          if (event is RawKeyDownEvent &&
              event.logicalKey.isAutogenerated == true) {
            myController.clear();
            textFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
          }
        },
        child: ...
```